# Using @Modifying annotation on an @EventListener in Spring Security/JPA data modifications are not persisted in the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a brute force attack prevention mechanics for a mini project. The issue I'm facing involves the method `registerLoginFailure` method, which is triggered by a BadCredentials Exception using the @EventListener annotation. The problem is that despite marking the method as @Transactional and attempting to update the locked property of the Clientz entity, the update is not persisted, even though the object is successfully found using findByPrincipal.

Method Structure: The registerLoginFailure method follows a structured approach to handle login failures. It checks the client's status, tracks login attempts, and updates the property accordingly. However, the issue lies within the update step.

BruteForceService

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    /**
     * Method to register every login failure of type BadCredentials for a Clientz.
     * this.bruteForceRepo stores in redis for caching and concurrency
     * @param auth of type Spring Core Authentication
     */
    @Transactional
    public void registerLoginFailure(Authentication auth) {
        var clientz = this.clientRepository.findByPrincipal(auth.getName()).orElse(null);

        if (clientz == null || !clientz.accountNoneLocked()) {
            return;
        }

        // Using redis for caching and concurrency
        var bruteEntity = this.bruteForceRepo.findByPrincipal(auth.getName());

        if (bruteEntity.isEmpty()) {
            this.bruteForceRepo.save(new BruteForceEntity(0, auth.getName()));
            return;
        }

        if (bruteEntity.get().getFailedAttempt() < this.MAX) {
            bruteEntity.get().setFailedAttempt(bruteEntity.get().getFailedAttempt() + 1);
            this.bruteForceRepo.update(bruteEntity.get());
            return;
        }

        this.clientRepository.lockClientAccount(false, clientz.getClientId());
        // TODO send client email to change password
    }
```

Query method `lockClientAccount` is responsible for updating the boolean property locked of the `Clientz` entity. It is defined using the `@Modifying` annotation, indicating that it performs a modification query. The query uses the JPQL syntax to update the entity. The flushAutomatically and clearAutomatically properties are set to true in the annotation, ensuring that the persistence context is cleared and flushed automatically before and after the query execution.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE Clientz c SET c.accountNoneLocked = ?1 WHERE c.clientId = ?2")
void lockClientAccount(@Param(value = "bool") boolean bool, @Param(value = "id") Long id);
```

Authentication Events which triggers `registerLoginFailure`

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEvents {

  @EventListener
  public void onFailure(AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent failures) {
     bruteForceService.registerLoginFailure(failures.getAuthentication());
  }

}
```

I should also say `lockClientAccount` query method functions correctly when invoked through a PUT RESTful call. However, it fails to work as expected when multiple or concurrent POST HTTP calls (login attempts) with incorrect credentials are made.

Comment: I would say JPA somewhere else saves client entity and overrides the value of `locked` property stored by `lockClientAccount` method, and believe that marking `locked`  property as non-updatable (i.e. `@Column(... updatable = false ...)`) should help. FYI, that is extremely hard to read your code due to reverse logic of `locked` property.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov sorry can you rephrase? You think JPA is overriding the property but I should try setting `accountNoneLocked` column property to `updateable = false`? And I refactored to make it less confusing

Comment: there are two ways how `accountNoneLocked` property could be updated in DB: 1) via direct JPQL update (your `lockClientAccount` method), 2) via explicit or implicit save of  `Clientz` entity. Since you are facing concurrency issues that is good idea to get a single point of truth of `accountNoneLocked` property state, i.e. disable updating `accountNoneLocked` property via saving entity.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov sorry it is still not clear to me. Are you suggesting I instead set `accountNoneLocked` column to updateable false via -> `@Column(name = "account_none_locked", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private boolean accountNoneLocked;` and save the entire entity object via `this.clientRepository.save(clientz)` because I am facing concurrency issues?

Comment: No, just set `updatable` to `false` and do not change anything else.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov ok just a moment. I'll make these changes and run integration tests

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov unfortunately, still the same issue.